# WatiN: How to type text in the Body allocated in other Frame

Tags: watin

This is link to TinyMCE redactor: [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/full.php)

I have a task: To type text in the textfield of TinyMCE. But this in not a textfield, this is a Body that doesn't have a method "TypeText();"

Please show me the code example, that can type the text in the TinyMCE Body

Answer (score 1):

tinyMce and watin don't play well together.
I generally have to use a combination of javascript (using `browser.eval`) and the `setAttributeValue('value')` of `textfield` objects.

Answer (score 1):

```js
string js = "tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('tekst');";
browser.Eval(js);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's always better to provide a short description for a sample code to improve the post accuracy :)

Comment: For inserting value into iframe body I use `document.getElementById('iframeContainerId').getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.write('new text')` as string for `js` (because I have more than one iframe and I don't want to be dependent on editor).

Comment: Updated example is: `string js = "document.getElementById('newComment').getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].‌​contentWindow.document.write('test1');";
browser.Eval(js);`

Answer (score 0):

You could set the Text property of the Body element.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar scenario (different editor / same concept) and got the body text set via javascript

```
string js = "document.getElementById('theEditor').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = 'Hello World!';";
myEditorPage.RichTextEditor.Eval(js);
```

Notes about the above code

- 'theEditor' is the ID of the editor frame.
- myEditorPage is a Page class I created
- RichTextEditor is the Frame object in my page class that corresponds to the 'theEditor' IDed frame.

Works like a champ.

My scenario

- IE8
- Win7
- Watin2.0
- Some 3rd party editor I don't remember.