# WatIn: Problem in setting text for Body

Tags: text, set, watin

I'm trying to put text in editable field of body type. As body doesn't have anything similar to type text. I'm not able to do it. I have already seen one question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003973/watin-how-to-type-text-in-the-body-allocated-in-other-frame) with same problem as mine. But reported answer doesn't work as Body.Text property is readonly. I can't set text in it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer on the other thread on how I did this in a frame body via Javascript

[WatiN: How to type text in the Body allocated in other Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003973/watin-how-to-type-text-in-the-body-allocated-in-other-frame/6782557#6782557)